# Paste extrusion in conical nozzle, partial differentiation equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, tensors, nonlinear-system

I have a physics problem that stuck me for a while because I cannot solve the mathematical equations below. Hopefully I can get some insights here:) Problem is basically a paste flows through a conical nozzle, and find the relation between inlet pressure ($P_0$) and output flow rate ($Q$). Equations have been simplified to the following ($r$ is the radical component in spherical coordinates):

1. $$
   0=-\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}+\frac{3\tau_{rr}}{r}+\frac{\partial\tau_{rr}}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\tau_{\theta r}}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\tau_{\theta r}}{r}\cot{\theta}
   $$
2. $$
   0=\frac{3\tau_{\theta r}}{r}+\frac{\partial\tau_{\theta r}}{\partial r}
   $$
3. $$
   \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}\tau_{rr}^2+\tau_{r\theta}^2} = \tau_y+K_s\left[\sqrt{3\left(\frac{u_r}{r}\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\ \left(\frac{1}{r}\ \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial\theta}\right)^2}\right]^{n_s}
   $$
4. $$
   Q=-\int_{0}^{\alpha}{u_r\bullet2\pi r\sin{\theta}}rd\theta
   $$

Boundary conditions: $ \left.u_r=0\right|_{\theta=\alpha}$,  $\left.\frac{\partial\tau_{\theta r}}{\partial\theta}=0\right|_{\theta=0}$, and $P=\left.P_0\right|_{r=R_0}, P=\left.0\right|_{r=R_1}$.

$u_r$ is the velocity of a unit volume element and it's a function of both $r$ and $\theta$. Nozzle geometry are constants ($R_0, R_1,\alpha$): inlet, outlet radius and half cone angle. And material properties are also constants ($\tau_y,K_s,n_s$): yield strength, flow consistency and flow index. The components of deviatoric stress tensor ($\tau_{rr}, \tau_{\theta r}$) are unknown.

Any comment is appreciated, or if you have concerns about the correctness of the equations, feel free to leave a message as well. Many thanks!!

Comment: Doesn't $2)$ imply $$\tau_{\theta r} = \frac{C_{1}}{r^{3}}$$ which you can then integrate to get $\tau_{\theta}$ and hence $\tau$?.

Comment: Thank you Mattos for your comment. Yes, you are right. But C1 is still an unknown function of θ, so how do I use it to replace the partial differentiation of $\tau_{\theta r}$ with respect to θ in (1)? Sorry I am not as smart in math...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Given that $$\tau_{\theta r} = \frac{C_{1}(\theta)}{r^{3}} \implies \tau_{\theta} = \frac{-C_{1}(\theta)}{2r^{2}} + C_{2}(\theta) \implies \tau = \frac{C_{3}(\theta)}{2r^{2}} + C_{4}(\theta)$$ where $C_{3}, C_{4}$ are the integrals of $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$, respectively, with respect to $\theta$. You also know from your boundary conditions that $C_{1}'(0) = 0$. Also, are you sure you have enough boundary conditions?

Comment: Hi Mattos, can you tell me what's the purpose to integrate $\tau_{\theta r}$ and get $\tau_\theta$ and then (I guess you intergrate again, but wrt. $\theta$) to get $\tau$?

Comment: The purpose is to find out what $\tau(r, \theta)$ is. If you know what it is, then you can substitute this into equation 1 to determine $p$ and equation 3 to determine (I think) $u$ and hence $Q$.

Comment: Well, I guess there is a misunderstanding here. $\tau_{\theta r}$ means the stress on the $\theta$ surface of a volume element and pointing along $r$ direction, $\tau_{rr}$ means the stress on $r$ surface and along $r$ direction. $\tau_{rr}$ and $\tau_{\theta r}$ are components in a stress tensor. As such, I am not sure if integrating one of them can result in $\tau$...